# Is there a more concise way of creating a context that is cancelled after receiving on a channel?

Tags: go, channel

I need to invoke a function that takes a [`Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) as a parameter. This block of code has access to a channel that is used for signalling that the operation should be cancelled.

Here is what I am currently using to cancel the `Context` when a value is received:

```
func doSomething(stop <-chan bool) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
        case <-stop:
            cancel()
        }
    }()
    longRunningFunction(ctx)
}
```

The intended control flow is as follows:

- If the task runs to completion, it will cancel the context, the `<-ctx.Done()` will fire, and the goroutine will terminate.
- If a value is received on `stop`, the context is cancelled, notifying the task that it should quit. Once again, the goroutine will terminate when this happens.

This seems overly complex. Is there a simpler way to accomplish the intended behavior?

Comment: If your actual code is working fine, this could be a better fitted for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @oliverpool I did and it was promptly closed and they suggested I ask here.

Comment: I think you need `defer cancel()` in the `doSomething`, otherwise you'll leak the gorutine when the `longRunningFunction` completes without being cancelled by the `stop` channel. You probably should also use `context.TODO()` instead of `context.Background()` as in the long run want to replace the stop cannel with context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ain mentionned, your code currently leaks the goroutine if the `longRunningFunction` runs to the end and nothing is sent on `stop` (or it is not closed): the `select` statement will never be fulfilled (the only way for the `context` to be done is when something comes out of `stop` to call `cancel`).

Here is a way to fix it (mainly an implementation of [@ain's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434939/is-there-a-more-concise-way-of-creating-a-context-that-is-cancelled-after-receiv#comment73928944_43434939)):

```
func doSomething(stop <-chan bool) {
    ctx := context.TODO() // because in the future, you might pass a ctx arg to this function, from which you could then "inherit"
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel() // to be sure to release the associated resources whatever happens (and prevent the following goroutine from leaking)
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
        case <-stop:
            cancel()
        }
    }()
    longRunningFunction(ctx)
}
```